# Kinetic energy problem for only one existing object

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, inertial-frames

If only a single object were to exist in the universe, what would be the measure of its kinetic energy?I mean what would determine the velocity of the object?I could be one,or could be hunder thousand meters per second or in fact a zero.I mean what would determine it? Sorry if this question is too unrealistic and totally violates any rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but kinetic energy is relative. I don't think kinetic energy can be defined for such an object. How would you define the speed of such an object? You would have to measure the distance it is travelling "relative to you" per unit time. This can't be done because even you don't exist in your situation. Enrgy is defined as the capacity to do work. On what body will this object do work on if no other body exists? However, if the universe is assumed to be a finite box, then, yes, that object  can do work on the universe and it has KE by choosing co-ordinate axes along the universe. However, if the universe is a finite box, then it is also inside something. BTW, a 'finite box like' universe will be just abother objext which violates the assumption that no other object exists.

Comment: The universe is approximately flat, and it's topology could be of a finite box, with opposite sides identified like in PacMan.